# How to sort elements in array without changing other elements indexes?

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
var arr = [5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4];
```

I'm trying to sort ONLY the elements that are **odd values** so I want this

output:

```
[1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4]
```

As you can see the **even elements** don't change their position. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Here's my code:

```js
function myFunction(array) {

  var oddElements = array.reduce((arr, val, index) => {
    if (val % 2 !== 0){
      arr.push(val);
    }
    return arr.sort();
  }, []);

  return oddElements;
}
console.log(myFunction([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]));
```

I know I can use slice to add elements to array, but I'm stuck on how to get the indexes and put the elements in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to keep track of the indicies of the odd numbers in the original array, and after `.reduce`ing and sorting, then iterate through the original odd indicies and reassign, taking from the sorted odd array:

```js
function oddSort(array) {
  const oddIndicies = [];
  const newArr = array.slice();
  const sortedOdd = array.reduce((arr, val, index) => {
    if (val % 2 !== 0) {
      arr.push(val);
      oddIndicies.push(index);
    }
    return arr;
  }, [])
    .sort((a, b) => a - b);
  while (oddIndicies.length > 0) {
    newArr[oddIndicies.shift()] = sortedOdd.shift();
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(oddSort([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]));
console.log(oddSort([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4, 11 ]));
```

Comment: your solution doesn't work when I pass this array: [5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4, 11 ], it supposes to return [1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4, 11], but it returns [1, 11, 2, 8, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: Ah, the 11 was throwing things off, since `.sort` sorts lexiographically - use a custom `.sort` function instead, see edit

Answer (score 8):

First sort only the **odd** numbers and put it in an array `oddSorted`. Then `map` through each element in the original array and check if the current element is **odd**, if **odd** replace it with the corresponding sorted number from the `oddSorted` array.

```js
function sortOddElements(arr){
   var oddSorted = arr.filter(ele => ele %2 != 0).sort((a, b) => a - b);
   var evenNotSorted = arr.map((ele, idx) => {
       if(ele % 2 != 0){
           return oddSorted.shift(); 
       }
       return ele;
     });
   return evenNotSorted;
}
var arr = [5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4];
console.log(sortOddElements(arr));
arr = [5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4, 11 ];
console.log(sortOddElements(arr));
```

Comment: easy-to-follow answer. now, can you think of a way to do this without having to do the `% 2 != 0` calculation twice per element? :D

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind is checking whether the current element is included in the `oddSorted` array, if yes then replace the current number with the first number from the `oddSorted` array.  This will also work as if the current element is included in the `oddSorted` array then it implies that the number is odd and hence there is no need to check it again. But do you think this will improve the performance?

Comment: You don't need to clone `arr`. Filter will return a new array anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little bit to fulfill your objective. Take a look below

```js
function myFunction(array) {

    var oddElements = array.reduce((arr, val, index) => {
        if (val % 2 !== 0) {
            arr.push(val);
        }
        return arr.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
    }, []);

    var index = 0;
    var finalElements = [];
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        var element = array[i];
        if(element %2 !==0) {
            finalElements.push(oddElements[index]);
            index++;
        } else {
            finalElements.push(element);
        }
    }
    return finalElements;
}
console.log(myFunction([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4, 11]));
```

Remember, the default sort function sorts the values alphabetically. That's why you can't just use arr.sort()

Comment: Nope, your solution doesn't work when I pass this array: [5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4, 11 ], it supposes to return [1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4, 11], but it returns [1, 11, 2, 8, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: Okay... I'm taking a look at it

Comment: The problem was with the sort function. The default sort function sorts the values alphabetically. That's why you can't just use arr.sort(). I modified the code to reflect your needs.